# Combining View's data from Google Analytics

Tags: view, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have moved a site from one domain name to another and created a new view for the new site. I want to create a report for the data and compare it to old data which would require data from the old site as well as the new site. Is there any way to get the data into only 1 dictionary.

I was thinking I might end up having to do 2 calls and then combining the data after?:

```
request = {
    'viewId': VIEW_ID,
    'dateRanges': [{'startDate': start_date.isoformat(), 'endDate': end_date.isoformat()}],
    'dimensions': [{'name': dim} for dim in dimensions],
    'metrics': [{'expression': metric} for metric in metrics]
}
request2 = {
    'viewId': OLD_VIEW_ID,
    'dateRanges': [{'startDate': start_date.isoformat(), 'endDate': end_date.isoformat()}],
    'dimensions': [{'name': dim} for dim in dimensions],
    'metrics': [{'expression': metric} for metric in metrics]
}
```

I am currently using the batch get method:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/basics

Answer (score 0):

You can only export (i.e. in Spreadsheet) and compare them later. For example, you could structure them to be imported as data source and display them with Data Studio or other data visualization software.

Comment: is there a good way to combine them after you have gotten 2 sets of data?

Comment: If they are a period after the other, just put them in sequence and then treat it as the only dataset

Comment: okay but is there any easy way to do that? or do you have to dig inside it and sort out what part of the dicts to combine?

Comment: You have to simulate what Analytics would do, sums, weightings, comparisons or try to import the data in the google data studio